# How to deleted an element inside XML string?

Tags: php, xml, regex

How can the `<title>` element be deleted inside this XML string?

```
$input=
'<items>dfd jdh flkdjf 
<title>My Test Title
</title>....
<store>my store 1</store>
</items>.....';

$output=
    '<items>dfd jdh flkdjf 
        ....
    <store>my store 1</store>
    </items>.....';
```

Thanks

Comment: ["Have you tried using an XML parser instead?" says the wise man bobince](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: ok, how you doing it with xmldocument?Its for unit test not for production soo regex can be good also

Comment: @BoltClock: That depends on the XML document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplexml

```
$str = '<items>1<title>lalala</title><others>...</others></items>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
unset($xml->children()->title);
$output = str_replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n", '', $xml->asXml());
```

Comment: SimpleXML lives up to its name, +1

Comment: Thanks, not working in real case, because title elements in other location. I give only simple example

Comment: is fixable, but need you to update again your question with the actual xml ... for multiple nodes, you need to loop into each node...

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with unknown input data, or with production code, **you should use an XML parser**.

If you're working in test environment *and the input data is known*:

```
$output = preg_replace('%<title>[^<]*</title>%', '', $input);
```

---

If you need to allow for attributes on the  tag, I suggest using a real XML parser, for maximum reliability and minimum chance of error.

Comment: thanks, but if title have atributes? <title: lat='778' etc..>

Comment: Updated.  Please note the caveat.