# Skip Element on XML document with php SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

before

```
<root>
 <child1>child1</child1>
 <child2>child2</child2>
 <child3>child3</child3>
</root>
```

I want the following result(after)

```
<root>
 <child1>child1</child1>
 <child3>child3</child3>
</root>
```

I'm using PHP and SimpleXML. How to skip a element on PHP?

Comment: Are you looking to re-print the modified XML document or do you just want to be able to parse 1 child element? Are you trying to parse only the first child element or remove the last child element? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: thank you for answering . I wanna remove the child2 element. please give me a solution

Comment: Has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+element+with+simplexml+php. Please point out why none of these help solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can consider this

```
$str = THE_XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
unset($xml->child2);
echo $xml->asXML);
```

Or refer this [How to deleted an element inside XML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423108/how-to-deleted-an-element-inside-xml-string/4423201#4423201) (looks like duplicated)

Comment: any reason why you dont closevote when you know that it's a duplicate and another duplicate is already given in the comments? Why answer again?