# How to delete an element from an XML tree where attribute is specific string in Simple XML PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So I want to delete a child from an XML string where an attribute is a specific value.

For Example:

```
<xml>
  <note url="http://google.com">
   Values
  </note>
  <note url="http://yahoo.com">
   Yahoo Values
  </note>
</xml>
```

So how would I delete the note node with attribute http://yahoo.com as the string for the URL?

I'm trying to do this in PHP Simple XML

Oh and also I'm loading it in as an XML Object with the SimpleXML_Load_String function like this:

```
$notesXML = simplexml_load_string($noteString['Notes']);
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php

Comment: where did you get `$noteString` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML does not have the remove child node feature,
there are cases you are can do [How to deleted an element inside XML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423108/how-to-deleted-an-element-inside-xml-string/4423201#4423201)
but is depend on XML structure

**Solution in DOMDocument**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($noteString['Notes']);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$items = $xpath->query( 'note[@url!="http://yahoo.com"]');

for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
  $doc->documentElement->removeChild( $items->item($i) );
}
```

Comment: That works, this solution also works too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remove nodes with SimpleXML by using `unset()`, though there is some trickery to it.

```
$yahooNotes = $notesXML->xpath('note[@url="http://yahoo.com"]');
// We know there is only one so access it directly
$noteToRemove = $yahooNotes[0];
// Unset the node. Note: unset($noteToRemove) would only unset the variable
unset($noteToRemove[0]);
```

If there are multiple matching nodes that you wish to delete, you could loop over them.

```
foreach ($yahooNotes as $noteToRemove) {
    unset($noteToRemove[0]);
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! this helps soooo much... and it isn't even my question!